# Enum with int represented as hex values

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum

```
public enum GridType
{
    Walkable = 0xFF000000,
    UnWalkable = 0xFF00000,
    Walked = 0xFF00000,
    Start = 0xFF00000,
    Destination = 0xFF00000
}
```

The int values represent argb color values. *(I know they are the same values, Ill put in the real ones later)*

---

**However the compiler throws an error:**

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion*
>   *exists (are you missing a cast?)*

**What can I do to fix this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make your `GridType` use `uint`:

```
public enum GridType: uint
{
    Walkable = 0xFF000000,
    // etc
}
```

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbbt4032(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I thought you could cast, but according to comments, that won't work.